# Installing R on Linux: configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https

Tags: r, installation

My issue is this:

Rigth now i have R 3.2 wooden xmas tree version, but theres some packages I need that dosent work on this version, so when i try to install the newest version, with

```
./configure
```

It returns the next error

```
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

I have a package called `libcurl3` installed. And its already in the last version.

Ill appreciate any help.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu based Peppermint 7 OS

Comment: https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Support-for-libcurl

Comment: as ./configure dosent work so theres no makefiles, make dosent work.

Comment: @Hack-R thanks for the answer, but : "linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.31.33)."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had similar problem, and I solve it by installing **libcurl4-openssl-dev**. This is one of packages, which R could use (R manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html)

Comment: I already solved it (don't remember if I did as you say) but thank you for your answer, R on linux is giving me a hard time.

Comment: how did you solve it? Can you please update your question/answer?

Comment: @Nanami sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: On ubuntu the library is libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: How did you find the name of this package? When I run apt list libcurl, that doesn't show up! I have to type the exact name, and at that point why even have a search function in the first place??

Answer (score 15):

In my case, it was due to libcurl installed in anaconda2 package, whose libcurl version did not support https.
I removed the path to anaconda2 from PATH variable, and it was all fixed.

Comment: this is actually worthy to notice

Comment: `curl --version` was showing a perfectly acceptable 7.68, as was `curl-config --version`. Even `conda list libcurl` was showing the same versioning. Nevertheless, deleting conda (as always!) solved my problems. One wonders if conda has every actually solved a problem instead of just creating them.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on centos 7. I fixed it by installing the `libcurl-devel`. The mistake I had made was that I just had `libcurl` installed and not it's development packages.

Comment: This fixed it for me for Amazon Linux

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04LTS. Unfortunately installing **libcurl4-openssl-dev** did not solve the issue. However, installing **libcurl4-gnutls-dev** did work.

Comment: Yes ubuntu 16.04 LTS has many trouble in R installation, but `sudo apt-get install  libcurl4-gnutls-dev` solve `libcurl` dependency

Comment: In my case, I have solved this problem by installing "gnutls"

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same solution with conda environment activated. After I deactivate the environment, I succeed. So before ./configure, just:

```
conda deactivate base
./configure
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem like this:

1. download curl-7.77.0 and run code: ./configure --with-ssl
2. Then I download R version 4.1.0, run ./configure again

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have a sudo privileges, run the following command to download the latest version of libcurl

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the similar problem. First, you need to look into the config.log file to find out the real error. For example, mine is shown as:

> /usr/include/string.h:548:5: error: unknown type name '__locale_t'
>        __locale_t __loc)

Which would be a problem due to the gcc I used. Then you can solve the problem based solving this issue, in my case, change another version of gcc works for me.