# How to make libcurl support for https? configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https

Tags: r, curl, libcurl

I was trying to install R 3.3.2 on CentOS6. 
but somehow I could not make libcurl support for https. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690232/installing-r-on-linux-configure-error-libcurl-7-28-0-library-and-headers-a) someone suggested to install  libcurl: libcurl-devel (rpm) or libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb).
I tried both(even though I realized later that libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb) is for 
debian), none of them worked.

```
 cd $HOME/Programme
 mkdir libcurl_devel
 cd libcurl_devel
 # download libcurl-devel-7.29.0-35.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
 rpm2cpio libcurl-devel-7.29.0-35.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm|cpio -i -d
```

in ".tcshrc":

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /host/u32/myusername/directory_for_rpm/usr/lib64:/host/u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl_devel/usr/include/:/host/u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl_devel/usr/lib64

source .tcshrc

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/R-3.3.2 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L//host/u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl_devel/usr/lib64" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/include -I/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/include  -I//host/u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl_devel/usr/include"

...
checking for curl-config... /host/u32/myusername/Programme/libcurl_devel/usr/bin//curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.29.0
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.28.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https
...
```

also see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347490/configure-error-libcurl-7-28-0-library-and-headers-are-required-with-suppor)
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this by adding -lcurl to LDFLAGS

Without that the test for https support doesn't link.  When I looked in config.log and searched for:

checking if curl supports https

I found that the underlying test failed to link because it could not reference the "curl_version_info" function

When I added -lcurl to LDFLAGS, this went away and the test passed.

Sheesh!

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. "skg" is a name of special interest for me, wondering whether that is an coincidence

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.My libcurl should meet the requirement but configure with failure.I solved it by comment some lines about  'test "x${have_libcurl}"' in the configure.sh.Hope useful for you!