# curl with ssl installed but compling R says libcurl find no https support

Tags: r, curl

I installed openssl, curl-7.57.0 with option `--witt-ssl` to enable https support under centos6.4, set

```
export CURL_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/curl-7.57.0/include
export CURL_LIBS=-L/usr/local/curl-7.57.0/lib
```

and compile R:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/R-3.4.3 --enable-R-shlib
```

But the command says https is not supported for libcurl:

```
...
checking for curl-config... /usr/local/curl-7.57.0/bin/curl-config
checking libcurl version ... 7.57.0
checking curl/curl.h usability... yes
checking curl/curl.h presence... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking if libcurl is version 7 and >= 7.22.0... yes
checking if libcurl supports https... no
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for https
```

However, command `curl-config --protocols` shows that HTTPS is supported:

```
DICT
FILE
FTP
FTPS
GOPHER
HTTP
HTTPS
IMAP
...
```

I refered to [Installing R on Linux: configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690232/installing-r-on-linux-configure-error-libcurl-7-28-0-library-and-headers-a) and tried to install libcurl4-openssl-dev, but it seems that that there are no this lib for centos6.4. How can I fix my problem?

Comment: See also.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690232/installing-r-on-linux-configure-error-libcurl-7-28-0-library-and-headers-a

Answer (score 4):

Finally I fixed the problem. It seems that the compilation cannot find corresponding `libssl.so` so that failed.  The following will fix the problem:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bzip2-1.0.6/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/xz-5.2.3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/pcre-8.41/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/curl-7.57.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/openssl-1.1.0g/bin:$PATH  

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bzip2-1.0.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/xz-5.2.3/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pcre-8.41/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/curl-7.57.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl-1.1.0g/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH    

export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/usr/local/xz-5.2.3/include -I/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/usr/local/pcre-8.41/include -I/usr/local/curl-7.57.0/include -I/usr/local/openssl-1.1.0g/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/usr/local/xz-5.2.3/lib -L/usr/local/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/usr/local/pcre-8.41/lib -L/usr/local/curl-7.57.0/lib -L/usr/local/openssl-1.1.0g/lib"
```

Comment: You have done an outstanding job. It took me few days to install R from source in centos 6.9. In centos 7 its not bad. Thank you so much.
I installed all the dependencies in /install/dep which makes the number of exports less.